# Übersetzung von "left to wonder what could have been"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, idiom, subjunctive

> He was left to wonder what could have been.

Die Phrase "[was left to wonder what could have been](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22was+left+to+wonder+what+could+have+been%22)" ist sehr idiomatisch in der englischen Sprache. Wie kann man das ins Deutsche übersetzen? Wäre es

> (a) Er wurde gelassen, sich zu fragen, was möglich hätte sein können.
>
> (b) Er wurde gelassen, sich zu fragen, was möglich gewesen sein konnte.

oder etwas anders?

Comment: Dein Deutsch ist so gut und liest so viel Spiegel, dass ich echt immer erstaunt bin, wenn du dann so wörtliche Übersetzungen bringst, die absolut kein Stück funktionieren :)

Comment: @Emanuel Manchmal möchte ich verschiedene Dinge einfach ausprobieren. In diesem Fall finde ich die Phrase in Frage eine schöne Phrase, und es wäre schön, wenn eine wörtliche Übersetzung funktionieren würde. Dass sie nicht funktioniert, kann ich schon verstehen. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das hängt EXTREM stark vom Kontext ab. Ich nehme mal zwei sehr gegensätzliche Beispiele von deinem Link:

> Miami was left to wonder what could have been after injuries cut short the season for two young stars in the game.
>
> It didn't seem fair. She was gone and he was left to wonder what could have been.

In beiden Beispielen ist die Aussage eigentlich im Kern die, dass ein Traum geplatzt ist. Man muss nicht viel "wondern". Im ersten Beispiel ist das besonders deutlich. Allen ist klar, was die Verletzung bedeutet. Daher wäre vielleicht ein direkter Satz die beste Wahl.

> Durch die Verletzung zweier Jungstars haben sich Miamis Aussichten für die diesjärige Saison verschlechtert.

Wenn es nun wirklich sehr wörtlich sein soll, dann vielleicht so:

> Nach der Verletzung zweier Jungstars beginnt man in Miami, sich zu fragen, was das für die weitere Saison bedeutet.

Das zweite Beispiel ist weit weniger technisch. Hier geht es vor allem um das "Den Träumen nachhängen".

> Es war nicht fair. Sie war weg und mit ihr all seine Träume auf ein gemeinsames Leben. (wenn der Kontext es hergibt)

Quintessenz ist also: Es gibt keine direkte Übersetzung und je mehr man versucht, das Original anzunähern, desto weniger passt es in die konkrete Situation.

Comment: Ich finde "Ihm/ihr bleibt nichts anderes übrig, als" ist eine ganz gelungene Übersetzung von "He/she is left to ..." und auch relativ nahe am Original.

Answer (score 2):

Nein, keine dieser Formulierungen ist richtig.

*To leave* wird nur dann mit *lassen* übersetzt, wenn es darum geht, eine bestehende Situation nicht zu ändern.

> die Türe offen lassen (to leave the door open)

*Lassen* kann aber auch *to let* bedeuten:

> Sie lassen ihn etw. tun.  (They let him do something.)

und wird im Gegensatz zu den davon abgeleiteten Formen wie *zulassen*, *zurücklassen* etc. (fast) nie im Passiv verwendet:

> <s>Er wurde etw. tun gelassen. (He was let do something)</s>

Stattdessen weicht man auf

> Man ließ ihn etwas tun.

aus.

Eine allgemein verwendbare Übersetzung dieses Idioms, die alle Aspekte abdeckt, ist schwer zu finden. Je nach Situation könnte man eine Formulierung mit *zurücklassen* oder *überlassen* versuchen.

> Er wurde seinen eigenen Gedanken/Überlegungen überlassen.
>   Sie ließen ihn tief in Gedanken versunken zurück.

oder auch mit *zurückbleiben*

> Er blieb in Gedanken versunken zurück.

Je nach gewünschter Stimmung kann jede dieser Formulierungen um den Aspekt der verlorenen Möglichkeiten/Gelegenheiten ergänzt werden, aber das Ergebnis wird wohl nicht so kompakt und idiomatisch wie das englische Original.

Comment: Äh... könntest du den zweiten Satz raus machen? "Lassen" wird sehr oft als "leave" übersetzt. Immer, wenn es darum geht etwas nicht zu ändern  (Leave it open, leave him, leave me alone, leave it to me... ). Eigentlich kann die ganze erste Hälfte weg, denn "lassen" wird sehr oft im Passiv verwendet. "Das Betonstück wird langsam runtergelassen", "Ich wurde vorgelassen",...

Comment: @Emanuel hm, im ersten Punkt gebe ich dir Recht. Aber das Passiv von lassen (ohne irgendwelche Zusätze - zulassen, einlassen, zurücklassen, rauf- und runterlassen etc. werden natürlich tatsächlich sehr oft im Passiv verwendet) fühlt sich für mich immer noch seltsam an. Vielleicht findet sich hier Stoff für eine Frage.

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde *he/she was left [to do sth]* übersetzen mit *Ihm/ihr blieb nichts anders übrig, als …*. In Deinem Beispielsatz:

> He was left to wonder what could have been.
>   Ihm blieb nichts anderes übrig, als sich zu fragen, was hätte sein können.

Der Beispielsatz

> Miami was left to wonder what could have been after injuries cut short the season for two young stars in the game.

Könnte beispielsweise übersetzt werden als

> Miami blieb nichts anderes übrig, als sich zu fragen, wie die Saison hätte ausgehen können, wenn die beiden Jungstars nicht verletzungsbedingt hätten aufgeben müssen.

oder

> Nachdem die beiden Jungstars die Saison verletzungsbedingt aufgeben mussten, blieb Miami nichts anderes übrig, als sich zu fragen, was möglich gewesen wäre.

Comment: Hmm. Schon richtig. Deine Übersetzung ist ziemlich nah am Wrotlaut des Originals. Aber ich glaube, das Englische einfach zu idiomatisch als das man das genau nachbauen müsste. Und rein semantisch ist es ein bisschen windschief. Miami hat viele Optionen was es machen kann, genauso der Verlassene. Sich fragen was hätte sein können, ist nur eine Option. Das Englische Original hat diese Exklusivität der Möglichkeit nicht. "Miami was left to wonder..." hier geht es nicht darum, dass Miami nix andere machen kann, sondern darum was Miami macht. Nämlich sich ärgern.

Comment: Bezüglich der Exklusivität muss ich Dir zustimmen. Es ist halt wir immer - Übersetzen ist schwierig, übertragen ist der Weg :-)